# Site-level [Authorize] in ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm writing small internal web app (decided to try asp.net for the first time). This app has no public pages, so i need to lock down every page.

First, i started to write this code in every single method of every single controller:

```
if (User.Identity is { IsAuthenticaed: true }) 
{
  // Do task
} else {
  throw new Exception("Unauthorized")
}
```

But then I discovered `[Authorize]`. Now i just writing it on top of every controller! But it's still quite manual, Is there a way to lock down entire website?

Comment: Do you want to add  `@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` OR `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))` in Layout ?

Comment: @QingGuo If I need to do it once, I can. How i can do that? And also, will it redirect to login page, like `[Authorize]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I need to do it once, I can. How i can do that? And also, will it
> redirect to login page, like [Authorize]

You can create an  a filter globally  for all controllers, actions, and Razor Pages ,create an [AuthorizeFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.authorization.authorizefilter?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

try to add below code :

```
 // Configure the custom policy
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireRole("Admin", "SuperUser")
            .Build();
 // Pass a policy in the constructor of the Authorization filter
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
```

Remember, this policy applies globally so you need to ensure your "Login" and "AccessDenied" pages are decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`, otherwise you'll end up with endless redirects.